# Trying to perform an action when a button is pressed

Tags: java, graphics

I am trying to make a game and I made a Button class using the JButton library.

This code is in the button class:

`@Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { pressed = true; }`

```
public boolean getPressed(){
    return pressed;
}
```

Then in the main java file:

```
    Button playButton = new Button("PLAY", frame);
    frame.add(playButton);
    
    
    while (true){
        
        
        if (playButton.getPressed())
            System.out.println("test");
        
    }
```

It never seems to print test even though I checked and the boolean value is being changed

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with JButton. But it seems that in your if statement in your while loop, there is no condition. Please reply if this helps!

Comment: thank you for your reply. I do not think this is the issue because it is a Boolean value so a condition is not necessary